# Metodos y variables estáticas en Javascript ES5 (sin usar "class") sin instanciar objetos?

Tags: variables, poo, ecmascript-2015, método

Buenas.
Creía que lo entendía pero no lo acabo de entender.
Quería replicar más o menos una variable o método estático de Java, que sin tener que crear una instancia de un objeto podía usar métodos estáticos.

Tengo varios problemas:

Si lo hago así:

```
const Obj = (function() {
     let _obj = function() {}           
     _obj.prototype.alertar = function(){
         alert("Hola mundo");
     }
     return _obj;
});
```

Es un método que se comparte con todas las instancias pero tendría que instanciar el objeto para poder usarlo según he probado.

```
const o1 = new Obj();
o1.alertar();
```

Si lo hago de otra manera:

```
const Obj = (function() {

    let _obj = function() {}
        _obj.alertar = function(){alert("Hola mundo");};
        return _obj;
})();

const o1 = new Obj();
Obj.alertar();
console.dir(Obj);
```

Sería lo más parecido a Java, ¿verdad? No necesito crear uns instancia y no se heredaría el método a hijos, ¿no?

¿A parte si me interesase que un método o variable no se pudiese sobreescribir, sin afectar a otras variables y métodos, pódria usar Object.defineProperty() para hacer variables y métodos estáticos que no se pudiesen sobrecargar sin tener que usar Object.freeze(), Object.seal() o Object.preventExtensions()?

Sé que se está usando Ecmascript6 pero uso la sintaxis antigua para crear objetos sin "class" porque me puede ayudar a entender mejor como funciona el lenguaje. Además según leí la sintaxis nueva no  es más que una mascara que de fondo hace lo mismo que la sintaxis antigua y no parece que se puedan hacer ciertas cosas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Quería replicar más o menos una variable o método estático de Java

**No trates de programar en un lenguaje como si fuese otro**, en su lugar, aprende como funciona el nuevo lenguaje y sigue su línea. ¿Por qué quieres usar JavaScript para que se parezca a Java? Simplemente no lo hagas.

El concepto de propiedad o método estático en Java quiere decir que dicha propiedad o método **no depende de una instancia, si no, de la clase misma**. ¿Qué se entiendo por esto? Bueno, es un poco complejo, en Java existen los llamados *Class loaders* los cuales se encargan de cargar las clases y registrarlas cuando se levanta la JVM. Si defines una propiedad o método estático, este es cargado también, esto no pasa con variables de instancia y métodos, ya que solo se carga su firma.

> **En JavaScript no existe en concepto de clases**

De hecho estés pensando en que esto es falso ya que en ES6 apareció `class`, pero esto no funciona como la gente nueva piensa. Aunque crees "clases" con `class` **estás creando funciones** con su respectivo prototipo. Esto es solo sintaxis, no tiene impacto.

Sin embargo, puedes *emular variables y métodos estáticos** mediante `Object.defineProperty`:

```js
function User () {
  
}

Object.defineProperty(User, 'age', {
  enumerable: true,
  configurable: true,
  writable: true,
  value: 23
});

Object.defineProperty(User, 'getInfo', {
  enumerable: true,
  configurable: true,
  writable: true,
  value: function () {
    return 'Hola, tengo ' + User.age + ' años';
  }
});

console.log(User.getInfo());
```

Como puedes ver, ahora `age` y `getInfo` están adheridas a la función `User`.

> Sería lo más parecido a Java, ¿verdad? No necesito crear una instancia y no se heredaría el método a hijos, ¿no?

Lo que haces se llama *Función factoría* y es bastante usada para crear objetos que tengan propiedades privadas y para usar agregación en lugar de herencia. Pero en realidad, no hay mucha diferencia, la diferencia es que usado una función constructora (`new`) añades un contexto (`this`) a la instancia, fuera de eso, ambas están creando objetos.

```js
function CreateBall (props) {
  let stub = { color, weight } = props;
  
  return {
    color: stub.color,
    weight: stub.weight,
    changeColor (color) {
      stub.color = color;
    },
    changeWeight (weight) {
      stub.weight = weight;
    },
    info () {
      console.log(stub.color, stub.weight);
    }
  };
}

const myBall = new CreateBall({
  color: 'blue',
  weight: 5
});

// encapsulamiento
myBall.color = 'red';
myBall.weight = 7;
myBall.info();

myBall.changeColor('red');
myBall.changeWeight(7);
myBall.info();
```

> ¿A parte si me interesase que un método o variable no se pudiese sobreescribir, sin afectar a otras variables y métodos, pódria usar `Object.defineProperty` para hacer variables y métodos estáticos que no se pudiesen sobrecargar sin tener que usar `Object.freeze`, `Object.seal` o `Object.preventExtensions`?

La ventaja de `Object.defineProperty` es que te da más flexibilidad: puedes hacerla readonly, no hacerla enumerable, etc. Por otro lado, `Object.freeze` **evita que se le puedan agregar nuevas propiedades a un objeto, eliminar o editar las ya existentes**. Es como si le pusieras un candado; útil en casos donde no quieres que editen un objeto, por ejemplo, por seguridad, etc.

El método `Object.seal` hace algo similar: **evita que añadas nuevas propiedades y que cambies la configuración de las ya existentes**, pero las propiedades pueden ser cambiadas.

El método `Object.preventExtensions` **previene que se añadan nuevas propiedades** como propias, pero se pueden añadir propiedades directamente en su prototipo.

Comment: Amo tus respuestas

Comment: @Jorius No es para tanto xD

Comment: @Lorthas no soy Jorius, soy Gustavo ;)

Comment: Muchas gracias a los dos. A @GustavoGarcía por la detallada explicación y a amenadiel por rematarla. Me queda bastante aclarado el tema. La verdad es que si pudiera elegir las 2 respuestas a la vez como definitivas lo haria. Voto positivo para los 2

Comment: Al final me lio con los nombres jaja

Answer (score 1):

Después de la respuesta de Gustavo, lo que se añada va a ser intrascendente, pero lo siguiente es un humilde complemento.

Estrictamente en ES5, sin let ni const, un método o propiedad estática se consideraba a aquella que se adosaba directamente al objeto y no a su prototipo.

```
var Miclase = function  (options) {
    this.options = options;
};

Miclase.prototype.getOptions = function () {
    return this.options; 
};

Miclase.metodoEstatico = function (a, b) {
    return a + b;
};
```

El método estático puede llamarse sin instanciar la clase, pero no tiene acceso al contexto de `this`. Esto es bastante similar a los métodos de una clase de PHP, aunque parecerse a PHP no es tan bien mirado en el presente.

Comment: Tus respuestas siempre dan gusto leerlas con atención, @amenadiel ;)